# Mocking a static method chain

Tags: java, junit, static, powermock, powermockito

I am trying to mock a static method

```
StaticClass.staticMethod(id).setContentType("text/plain").build();
```

I was able to mock static method and its return type using PowerMockito as below :

```
PowerMockito.when(StaticClass.staticMethod(id)).thenReturn(returnValue);
```

But How do I send that value to the chained method setContentType()?

Answer (score 2):

You need multiple whens. You'll need to mock a couple more objects `staticMethod` and `contentType`.

```
PowerMockito.when(StaticClass.staticMethod(id)).thenReturn(staticMethod);
PowerMockito.when(staticMethod.setContentType("text/plain")).thenReturn(contentType);
PowerMockito.when(contentType.build()).thenReturn(returnValue);
```